# Routing notifications coming from service catalog

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, aws-service-catalog

I want to send notifications coming from the service catalog to different queues. You can see in below diagram

[image]

But routing in SNS requires attributes on the message. & service catalog is not adding any attributes. The key using which I want to route messages is in the body of that message.

Any solution which require changes in any component is OK.

Comment: You could have it go to one queue where an interim categorizer checks the message and then transfers it to one of the other two queues.